# How to replace the string based on an expression

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having a string where i'm using some placeholders to replace it with some values based on an object.

It is like the following:

```
Hello User <#= string#>
```

I need to find the expression `<#= string #>` , the string is not static. The expression should be replaced with a value.

How can this be done with a regex? Please help. There are so many placeholders and string is actually the property name of a class.

Comment: myString = myString.Replace("<= UserName #>", myValue);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code will use replacements from dictionary for each matched group in input:

```
string input = "Hello <#= UserName #> from <#= City #>. Bye, <#= UserName #>!";
var replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "UserName", "Bob" },
    { "City", "Atlanta" }
};

var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\<#=\s*(\w+)\s*#\>", 
                           m => replacements[m.Groups[1].Value] );
```

If it is possible that some keys can not present in replacements dictionary, than do check before trying to get key value:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\<#=\s*(\w+)\s*#\>", m =>
{
    string key = m.Groups[1].Value;
    if (!replacements.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        Logger.Warn("Unknown key found: " + key); // Nice to log this case
        return m.Groups[0].Value; // throw, return default, or keep unchanged
    }

    return replacements[key];
});
```

Output:

```
"Hello Bob from Atlanta. Bye, Bob!"
```

Comment: Thank You for understanding my query. This is what i needed.

Comment: I appreciate the OP was obsessed with using a regex, and you have provided that. However, the resultant solution is ridiculously complex and difficult to read compared with a simple for loop and `string.Replace`. Sometimes it is better to give the OP what they need, rather than what they are asking for.

Comment: @DavidArno one line of code is *ridiculously complex* for you? Then yes, for loop with huge amount of created in-memory strings is your choice.

Comment: Your "proper" solution, which checks whether the key exists, is not one line of code.

Comment: @deepak ternary operator, if you wish. But I don't see anything complex here. One `if` condition. Also, I'd added logging here to notify that unknown placeholder was found in text. Any experienced programmer will put all this staff in `ReplacePlaceholders` method, which will show intent without need to read loops or regex patterns

Comment: Regex really is not necessary here.. [why complicate things](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html)?

Comment: @dtsg how do you define whether it necessary or not? It is very useful to find placeholders in text

Comment: @lazyberezovsky It is not necessary when you have far simpler alternatives. It is useful yes, I'm not denying that.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need regex to do that, a simple replace should work:

```
string foo = "Hello User <#= UserName #>";
string name = "deepak";
string bar = foo.Replace("<#= UserName #>", name);
```

Results in:

> Hello User deepak

Edit:

You still don't need regex to do this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> placeholders = new Dictionary<string, string>();
placeholders.Add("<#= UserName #>", "deepak");
placeholders.Add("<#= Address #>", "foo address");
placeholders.Add("<#= City #>", "foo city");
placeholders.Add("<#= State #>", "foo state");
placeholders.Add("<#= Zip #>", "foo zip");

string htmlTemplate ="... etc.";

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in placeholders)
{
     htmlTemplate = htmlTemplate.Replace(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

It is up to you to choose how you populate the `Dictionary<string, string>`

Comment: This wont work for me as there are somany place holders like this. I cannot hardcode and replace it like this.

Comment: What other placeholders do you have in the string?

Comment: Its an html template filled with placeholders for Address, City, State, Zip etc

Comment: As long as you don't have multiple user name placeholders e.g. `<#= UserName #>` more than once in the same string, then this will be fine. Do you have more than one of the same type of placeholder in the string?

Comment: You still don't need regex, replace will work, you will just have to supply a different placeholder to match against. You would need to do this if you were using regex anyway.

Comment: Your update won't work as you end up writing the same value to UserName, Address etc.

Comment: It's an example, perhaps you noticed that `somevalue` has not been defined anywhere? Obviously it won't work. I will update it for correctness, though didn't feel it was necessary to include sample data to replace with.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Unfortunately, the silly timeout on vote changes has hit me, so I'm stuck with my downvote unless you edit again. Sorry. :(

Comment: That's fine, no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

How you will define so many regex for so many placeholders, it is not at all good. As larger the text of string to replace larger will be the execution time. Try StringBuilder or string to do this task.

```
System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder("sample <#test>");
builder.Replace("<#test>", "test");
builder.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this for various values, and not just UserName, you could use:

```
public void ReplaceStuff(string stuffToReplace, string newStuff){
  return originalString.Replace("<#= " + stuffToReplace + " #>", newStuff);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Regex r = new Regex("<#= UserName #>");
        string result = r.Replace(input, MyValue);
```